# Run sikuli scripts with minimal installation on Linux

Tags: java, python, linux, gui-testing, sikuli

I would like to add sikuli scripts to my repository and make it available to others with minimal installation on Linux. [There](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/196785) are instructions how to run scripts without installation on Windows, but it's more complicated on Linux.

Does anyone have experience or advice with this problem?